# Passing element attribute to JQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page with several hyperlinks on it that share the same id but have a custom property linkID that differs. I know it is not a good practice but that is not something I can change at this point. I need to open a modal dialog box whenever a link is clicked. For that I am using JQuery. Now I need to pass the linkID property to the Jquery function. I tried using $("#hlk1").attr("LinkID") and $(this).attr("LinkID") but neither worked. It comes up as "undefined".

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="Script\jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="Script\jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#hlk1").click(function(){ 
        var linkId=$("#hlk1").attr("LinkID");
        // initialize dialog
        var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({ 
            autoOpen: false, height: 500, width: 350
        });

        // load content and open dialog
        dlg.load('page2.html?id=' + linkId).dialog('open');
    });
});

 </script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="hlk1" linkID="305">Click here</a>
<a href="#" id="hlk1" linkID="890">Click here</a>
<div id="dialog">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stopped reading at *"...share the same id"* <- that's an error!

Comment: Check your case.  You have linkID with a lowercase "L" in the a tag but LinkID in your jQuery has an uppercase "L".

Comment: Don't use custom attributes. Use `data-linkID` intead of `linkID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `linkID` not `LinkID`:

```
var linkId= $("#hlk1").attr("linkID");
```

You should also take advantage of using the `data` attributes.

As an additional note you may have issues with selecting multiple elements with the same identifier with `jQuery`, therefore it may be better to use a class and attach a handler.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="hlk1" linkID="305">Click here</a>
<a href="#" class="hlk1" linkID="890">Click here</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".hlk1").on("click", function() {
   var linkId = $(this).attr("linkID");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't repeat ID's in a page so use class instead. Then inside the click handler `this` is the element that event occurred on

```
<a href="#" class="hlk1" linkID="305">Click here</a>
<a href="#" class="hlk1" linkID="890">Click here</a>
```

JS

```
 $(".hlk1").click(function(){ 
        var linkId=$(this).attr("linkID");
        // initialize dialog
        var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({ 
            autoOpen: false, height: 500, width: 350
        });

        // load content and open dialog
        dlg.load('page2.html?id=' + linkId).dialog('open');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method. Also use data-attributes properly (`data-linkId = "305"`)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#hlk1").click(function(){ 
        var linkId=$(this).data("LinkID");
        // initialize dialog
        var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({ 
            autoOpen: false, height: 500, width: 350
        });

        // load content and open dialog
        dlg.load('page2.html?id=' + linkId).dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: $(this).data("LinkID") still came up as undefined